# How to do a "if... then, but also if.... then but if neither do...."

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have made a simple application to play the game FizzBuzz in c++, although this isn't necessarily a c++ question, what is the best way to make an if statement so it does the following:

if(x) then: a,
if(y) then: b,
if(x) and if(y) then: a and b,
if neither then:

this is my current approach:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int factor1 = 7;
    int factor2 = 15;
    bool found = false;
    string factor1_word = "Fizz";
    string factor2_word = "Buzz";
    int n = 1000;
    for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
    {
        if (i % factor1 == 0)
        {
            cout << factor1_word;
            found = true;
        }
        if (i % factor2 == 0)
        {
            cout << factor2_word;
            found = true;
        }
        if (found == 0)
        {
            cout << i;
        }
        cout << endl;
        found = false;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which works but I feel like it isn't the most readable nor the best way to do it.

Any advice would be great, thanks.

Comment: Looks like a question for the code review stack exchange

Comment: By what attribute would you identify the "better" way over a "pretty good" way? Have a look at the definition of the tag: "optimization" ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/optimization/info ) and pick one. I guess you will like the last one "teacher happiness".

Comment: Treating this as a code review, this looks good to me. This is perfectly readable imo.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu I think readability of the output is meant, which is much less pronounced than readability of the code (which is good, I agree).

Comment: No so much as a better way, but this way just feel very clunky I just thought there might have been a way to write that sort of statement in the language similar to how an if followed by an else if works

Comment: I thought FizzBuzz was using the numbers 3 and 5 as factors.  What's the deal with the number 7?

Comment: Assigning `true` and then comparing `==0` is kind of contradictory. Why not `if (!found)`?

Comment: Instead of `i < n+1` use `i <= n` and let the compiler do the appropriate optimization.

Comment: Can both ever happen at the same time?

Comment: @Chipster Do you mean whether there are numbers < 1000 which can be divided by 7 and by 15? Try 7 * 15 == 105.

Comment: @Chipster yes... `7 * 15 = 105` for example...

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You want to achieve this "if(x) then: a, if(y) then: b, if(x) and if(y) then: a and b, if neither then:". Obviously you imply however, that you do NOT want the "a"-reaction in case of "x & y" on top of the reaction specifically for that case; and that you generally only want one reaction.

That is all, code it exactly like that.

```
if     (x && !y)  { a(); }
else if(y && !x)  { b(); }
else if(x &&  y)  {a(); b(); /* or maybe a_and_b() to make sense */}
else {/* nothing */}
```

The  `&& !` implement the "but not if ...". Note the logical AND operator `&&` instead of the bit-operator `&` (which I got wrong initially, more or less a typo), which onyl by chance gets the desired behaviour in some cases. 
The  `else`s make the "always only one".
The last `else {}`, without an `if` turns the "do nothing for 'neither x nor y'" into
"do nothing for any case not explicitly covered". That is a practice I recommend, to always code the "everything else" explicitly, for a chance to notice when you did not actually all possible cases.

For getting all the (in this case of two binary inputs four) cases cleanly sorted out, read up on Karnaugh Veitch diagrams ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map )and the corresponding logic optimisations.

Comment: This is significantly less readable than OP's original solution, and more convoluted than it needs to be. `else if(x && y) { a(); b();}` is redundant if you just remove the `!x` and `!y` conditions on the first two ifs. If something besides `a()` and `b()` were called when both conditions were true than this would make sense, but since they are the same its much cleaner code to just let fall through happen. He doesn't imply that he does not want the `a` reaction in the case of `x && y`. Quite the opposite, actually. He is pretty explicit that he wants both to happen in that case.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu Thanks for your input. Unluckily I was on the running track when I realised myself that made the mistake with the `&` instead of the `&&`. Concerning the readability we are obviously of different opinion. I agree with you that the code is readable. But if you consider the output it seems clear, at least to me, that the readabiltiy of the output was the problem. "FizzBuzz" is less desirable (at a guess) than e.g. "Fizz, Buzz", which would be an output for x&&y which cannot be achieved by OPs code. That would be something for an explicity reaction `a_and_b()` as ...

Comment: ... I proposed in the comment on that line. On that assumption (I admit it is an assumption) the rest of the code is the logical consequence. Also, the structure can be easily applied to logicall optimised analysis of possible inputs and desired outputs (with the help by Karnaugh), which is not as easily true for the more "creative" way of implicit ORing outcomes with a common flag. Opinions and assumptions divide. I thank you for expressing yours.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Exactly. I was elsewhere when I realised. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)

always start from zero since 0 is the the starting index in most data structures like arrays or vector, and try to keep your code simple and easy to read, the way u did is most efficient way to do it because the runtime efficiency of that for loop is going to be of order o(n) whatever the case maybe

you can use (!found) instead of (found==0)

Comment: I was going to start the for loop from zero but I some what wanted to make the program simulate the real game in which you wouldn't start from zero

Comment: And I thought it was more readble to start from loop from 1 rather than having i +1  or something like that

Answer (score -3):

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)

always start from zero since 0 is the the starting index in most data structures like arrays or vector, and try to keep your code simple and easy to read, the way u did is most efficient way to do it because the runtime efficiency of that for loop is going to be of order o(n) whatever the case maybe

you can use (!found) instead of (found==0)

Comment: The first `else` makes the program behave incorrectly and should be removed. The second `found = true;` is redundant.

Comment: Yeah this behaves differently, as it would not trigger both conditions, after the first if is triggered, it won't bother to check to other one.

Comment: Please explain your solution, among other things in order to help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code-writing service.

Comment: Now that you removed both `else`s, your code is essentially no different from what OP has.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The redundant `found = ` is the one with the `false`, not any one with `true`. Isn't it?

Comment: @Yunnosch There used to be an `else` in there, the answer was edited. But yeah, the `found = false;` is unnecessary in any case.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I saw both versions. In both I could see the redundance of the `false` line. In neither I see the redundance of any `true` line. I honestly would like to be explained what I miss (though I admittedly think that I did not...).

Comment: @Yunnosch If the `else` (before `if(!found)`) is there, and `i % factor2 == 0` is true, then `!found` won't be checked at all, so setting `found` in the `i % factor2 == 0` branch does nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202170/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-holyblackcat).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat OK, now I got it. The line does have an effect on the flag (which I shortsightedly considered to break the redundance), but with the else the flag does not have an effect on the output (which I now accept as a more indirect form of redundance) and gets reset. Thanks for making me think longer.